# getdates() in bootstrap-datepicker does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I created a [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) with [this generator](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/). You can see the result [here](http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/download/datepicker/). [The docs are saying](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#getdates), that it's easy to get the dates with

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDates');
```

They say as well:

*Returns a list of localized date objects representing the internal 
date objects of the first datepicker in the selection. 
For use with multidate pickers.*

Unfortunatley, this does not work in my example above. If I click on the button after I choose the dates, I just get an jQuery object, not a list of dates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console.log($('#datepicker').datepicker('getDates')) ?

Comment: This prints the jQuery object to the console, not an array of dates.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue. The problem is that you're not using a multidate picker, but a range picker. The current datepicker does not have a method to get the dates from all pickers.

That's not a big problem, since each date can be easily obtained by using another function: [`getDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#getdate)

I've made a jsfiddle to get the dates and count the number of days between two dates. You can see the full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/7abqJ/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
        multidate: true,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        startDate : new Date("2014-02-01"),
        endDate : new Date()
    }).on("changeDate", function(e){
        $begin = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
        $end = $('#end').datepicker('getDate');
    });
});
```